# how to access localhost asp.net core web api from outside

Tags: reactjs, api, native, wep

I have react native app.i want get data from the asp.net core web API .I want to  to access localhost asp.net core web API from outside(from react native app)

Answer (score 0):

You can use many 3rd party library for HTTP request such as axios, fetch even XMLHttpRequest as you want to access core web API. You can use the following approaches it doesn't matter what's your endpoint.

```
 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
         method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
         console.log(responseJson);
         this.setState({
            data: responseJson
         })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
      });
```

using XMLHttpRequest

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
      console.log(xhr.responseText)
    })
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
    xhr.send()
```

using axios

```
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
  });
```